# Como convierto una condicion if en un metodo que pueda ser llamado en EXTJS6?

Tags: extjs

tengo una grilla en EXTJS donde al agregar una fila (dia), esta se rellena con horarios y verifica que la suma de todas las horas no sea mayor a X valor, y si no es mayor, permite agregar mas filas hasta que complete las horas.

Hay una seccion donde hace la comprobacion de las horas semanales y si se completan envia una alerta de que no se pueden agregar mas horas.

Este es el codigo:

```
onAgregarDiaClick: function(button, e, eOpts) {
    var dias_store      = button.up('grid').getStore().count();
    console.log(dias_store);

    var dif_hora_total = 8.80;
    var cuenta_grid    = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=grid_jornadaLaboral]')[0].getStore().getCount();

    if(dias_store < 7)
    {
        if(dias_store == 6)
        button.disable();

        grideditable = button.up('grid');
        var opcion = new form_48.model.JornadaLaboral.mdl_JornadaDiaria({
            'dia_codigo'    : 8,
            'dia_nombre'    : 'Seleccione...',
            'entrada_manana': '08:30',
            'salida_manana' : '13:18',
            'entrada_tarde' : '15:00',
            'salida_tarde'  : '19:00'
        });

        var editor = button.up('grid').editingPlugin;
        //editor.cancelEdit();

        if(cuenta_grid === 0){

            button.up('grid').getStore().insert(dias_store+1, opcion);
            button.up('grid').getStore().sort('dia_codigo', 'ASC');

        }
        //editor.startEditByPosition({row: dias_store+1, column: 0});



    }

    var horas_semanales = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('numberfield[name=num_horasSemanales]')[0].getValue();


    if( dif_hora_total < horas_semanales ){

        if( cuenta_grid > 0 ){


            for (var i = 0; i < cuenta_grid; i++)
            {

                var ent_mnna = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=grid_jornadaLaboral]')[0].getStore().data.items[i].data.entrada_manana;
                var sal_mnna = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=grid_jornadaLaboral]')[0].getStore().data.items[i].data.salida_manana;
                var ent_tard = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=grid_jornadaLaboral]')[0].getStore().data.items[i].data.entrada_tarde;
                var sal_tard = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[itemId=grid_jornadaLaboral]')[0].getStore().data.items[i].data.salida_tarde;


                var ent_mnna_sum = form_48.app.getController('FormateoNumero').fecha_hora(ent_mnna);
                var sal_mnna_sum = form_48.app.getController('FormateoNumero').fecha_hora(sal_mnna);
                var ent_tard_sum = form_48.app.getController('FormateoNumero').fecha_hora(ent_tard);
                var sal_tard_sum = form_48.app.getController('FormateoNumero').fecha_hora(sal_tard);

                //OBTENEMOS LAS DIFERENCIAS DE HORAS DE LA MANANA Y DE LA TARDE (EJ. 8:30 -13:18 = 04:48)
                dif_hora_manana = form_48.app.getController('FormateoNumero').resta_horas(ent_mnna_sum,sal_mnna_sum);
                dif_hora_tarde  = form_48.app.getController('FormateoNumero').resta_horas(ent_tard_sum,sal_tard_sum);


                //SUMAMOS LAS DIFERENCIAS DE HORAS DE LA MANANA Y DE LA TARDE PARA OBTENER EL TOTAL DE HORAS TRABAJADO AL DIA.
                dif_hora_total = dif_hora_total + form_48.app.getController('FormateoNumero').suma_horas(dif_hora_manana,dif_hora_tarde);

                // Ext.ComponentQuery.query('numberfield[name=num_horas_grid]')[0].setValue(num_horas_grid);
                console.log(dif_hora_total);



            }

            if(dif_hora_total === horas_semanales){

                Ext.ComponentQuery.query('displayfield[name=dsp_cumple_horas]')[0].setValue('SI');

               console.log(horas_semanales);
            }else{

                Ext.ComponentQuery.query('displayfield[name=dsp_cumple_horas]')[0].setValue('NO');
            }

            if(dif_hora_total <= horas_semanales){

                //alert("dif_hora2: "+dif_hora_total);
                button.up('grid').getStore().insert(dias_store+1, opcion);
                button.up('grid').getStore().sort('dia_codigo', 'ASC');

            }else{

                Ext.Msg.show
                ({
                    title:'Advertencia',
                    msg: 'No se puede ingresar la jornada ya que las horas exceden el maximo establecido en el campo <center><b>"Horas Semanales"</b></center>',
                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.WARNING,
                    buttons: Ext.MessageBox.OK
                });
            }



        }//fin if cuentagrid
    }



},
```

Desde la declaracion de  la variable var horas_semanales en adelante quiero que sea un metodo que se pueda llamar, algo asi como en java colocarle comprobacion(){} y que se pueda llamar desde dentro del metodo onAgregarDiaClick, por que en estos momentos es solo una condicion if dentro de onAgregarClick, pero quiero hacer uso de esa condicion desde aca tambien, en el metodo onTimefieldSelect

```
onTimefieldSelect: function(combo, record, eOpts) {
    var value = new Date(combo.getValue());


    hora = value.getHours();
    minuto = (value.getMinutes() === 0)?'00':value.getMinutes();
    console.log('hora '+hora+' '+minuto);
    combo.setValue(hora +':'+minuto);
},
```

Lo que hace en estos momentos el codigo es que cuando se agrega una fila nueva, comprueba la cantidad de horas con la condicion IF y mi idea es que cada vez que modifique un valor en la grilla, vaya a ese metodo nuevo de comprobacion  (q remplaza al if) para q sume todas las horas de la grilla y recien ahi compruebe si estan bien o no, por que en estos momentos comprueba solo al agregar una nueva fila.

Por eso mi idea es convertir esa condicion if que esta onAgregarDiaClick en un metodo q pueda ser llamado de onTimefieldSelect, pero no se como se hace eso en EXTJS.

Como lo puedo hacer?, existe una mejor manera aun??

Muchas gracias!!